# How can i remove this field 'to_names' and still get the code working fine?

Tags: php, html, email, post

This Email sending Code works well, but when i try to remove the following field 'to_names'. the code stops working. I am new to PHP coding Please can someone help show me how to remove it and still get my code working well. Thanks.

```
    <?php
    $to_emails = $_POST['to_emails'];
    $to_names = $_POST['to_names']; // The code stops working when i remove this line. Please help.
    $from_email = $_POST['from_email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];

    $explode_emails = array_map('trim', explode(",", $to_emails));
    $explode_names = array_map('trim', explode(",",$to_names));

    $recipients = array_combine($explode_emails, $explode_names);

    $i=0;
    foreach($recipients as $email => $name) {
        $headers = 'From: ' . $from_email;
        $headers .= "\r\nReply-To: " . $from_email;
        $headers .= "\r\nX-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

        $finalMessage = $name . ",\r\n" . $message;

    $success = mail($email, $subject, $finalMessage, $headers);        

        echo "<font color='#FF0000'>" . $i . " Emailed: " . $name . " : " . $email . "</font><br />";

        $i++;
    }

    // redirect to success page 
    if ($success){
      print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=login.php\">";
    }
    else{
      print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: u need to remove this as well `$explode_names = array_map('trim', explode(",",$to_names));`

Comment: Why do you want to remove that line of the code? There are some other part of your code which are dependent to that line! If the current code if working perfectly, then what do you exactly want to do in the first place by removing that line?

Comment: @parkway Not also that line, but the line after it `$recipients = ...` and then the `foreach(` line and so on... all these lines of the code are somehow using the content of the `$_POST['to_names']` variable

Comment: yes i know but $to_names already declared at top of the code. so anythings that associate with the $to_names need to be removed to avoid the code error. But in this case he only remove the declaration of $to_names but at bottom code he still using the $to_names where the declaration of $to_names has been removed. so anything related to $to_names all need to be removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code: (untested)

```
if(!isset($_POST['to_emails'],$_POST['from_email'],$_POST['message'],$_POST['subject'])) {
    $failure=true;
    echo "Oops, insufficent mailing values posted";
}else{
    foreach(explode(",",$_POST['to_emails']) as $index=>$email){
        $email=trim($email);
        $headers = 'From: ' . $_POST['from_email'];
        $headers .= "\r\nReply-To: " . $_POST['from_email'];
        $headers .= "\r\nX-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

        if(mail($email, $_POST['subject'], "\r\n{$_POST['message']}", $headers)){
            echo "<font color='#FF0000'>{$index} Emailed: {$email}</font><br />";
        }else{
            $failure=true;
            echo "Oops, something went wrong on email index $index to $email<br>";
        }
    }
}

echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=",(!$failure?"login.php":"error.htm"),"\">";
```

- Check for sufficient posted values.
- Overwriting a `$success` string will only be true of the last iteration.
- Don't declare new variables for single-use values.
- Don't iterate an array twice (`array_map()` then `foreach()`) when one pass can do it all.  Pack `trim()` into the foreach loop.
- Use the indexes from `explode()` rather than implementing a counter with iterated incrementation.
- Not included -- value validation/sanitizing is highly advised!
- Check for failures after all processes are complete.
- Condense the redirect at the end with an inline conditional.

Comment: Thanks alot mickmackusa, that was helpful. But i need the code to send message as html. How can i do that? I tried adding the following code but the problem is that sent mal stops showing "SENT FROM EMAIL"

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

Where exactly in the code should i add this and still have the code working perfectly?

Answer (score 0):

I modefired Your code, try this:

```html
<?php
    $to_emails = $_POST['to_emails'];
    //$to_names = $_POST['to_names']; // The code stops working when i remove this line. Please help.
    $from_email = $_POST['from_email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];

    $explode_emails = array_map('trim', explode(",", $to_emails));
    //$explode_names = array_map('trim', explode(",",$to_names));

    //$recipients = array_combine($explode_emails, $explode_names);
    $recipients = $explode_emails;

    $i=0;
    foreach($recipients as $email) {
        $headers = 'From: ' . $from_email;
        $headers .= "\r\nReply-To: " . $from_email;
        $headers .= "\r\nX-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

        $finalMessage = $email . ",\r\n" . $message;

    $success = mail($email, $subject, $finalMessage, $headers);        

        echo "<font color='#FF0000'>" . $i . " Emailed: " . $email . "</font><br />";

        $i++;
    }

    // redirect to success page 
    if ($success){
      print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=login.php\">";
    }
    else{
      print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

does $to_names means the user name of the people you send to? if it is,you can define an default value for the variable $to_names.
$to_names = $_POST['to_names']?$_POST['to_names']:'my friends';